# Mount Point in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, mount-point

I'm trying to create a mount point using Powershell. it's done locally, and here is the code & issue i'm having.

```
$choice = "t"
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path "E:\Data\Riptide\Ariis\Ris\Docs\interPrimary1\"
$orgdrive = "E:\Data\Riptide\Ariis\Ris\Docs\interPrimary1\"
$driveLetter= $Choice + ":\"
$driveinfo=get-wmiobject win32_volume | where { $_.driveletter -eq $choice + ":" } | select-object DeviceID
Mountvol $orgdrive $driveinfo
```

When executed, I get that the parameter is incorrect.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to try :

```
mountvol $orgdrive $driveinfo.DeviceID
```

For the future you can test :

```
$driveinfo| Get-Member
```

You can find [here](http://www.silogix.fr/developpement/outils/c_param.aspx) a tool that allow you to test the command line parameters.